# Will building my simple dc motor out of metal short the circuit?

Tags: dc-motor

i have the shaft and the thing wire coiled on made out of metal entirely, i'm going to stick the positive and negative ends of the wire on the shaft. The brushes will lean on the metal shaft.

[image]

Comment: this is either total nonsemse - a big short circuit- or a proper motor. I need an image to decide are the poles separated. It sounds like a short circuit: pure metallic noninsulated winding and the ends are connected together. But in some AC motors the connection is the same and it still works. So give a draft and let us to see. Tell where is some insulation, too.

Comment: @user287001 i uploaded a diagram, where insulation is needed?

Comment: Please, you need a proper commutator for a DC motor.

Comment: Where are your magnets?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, it is on the stator.  Only the rotor is shown. BTW do you speak Esperanto?

Comment: No Esperanto. Just a big fan of HH and Slippery Jim.

Answer (score 1):

The need for insulation:

- the wire must be insulated and also something must be between the wire and the metal to protect the insulation against the sharp edges of the metal.
- You must have proper contact plates against the brushes. Those contact plates must be insulated fom the shaft and from each other. Those contact plates should be curved to get long enough durating contact to the brushes.
- the brushes must be insulated from the chassis of your motor if the chassis is metallic.

More insulation: A thin foil inside the winding is inefficient. The winding needs some cross-sectional area to make a substantial magnetic field and that area must be full of iron. The iron should not be uniform, but several thin foils that are insulated from each other by thin paper or plastic sheets. That insulation prevents eddy currents which would easily eat a great part of the rotating energy.

Note: This all was well known about 150 years ago.

ADDENDUM (inspired by skvery's excellent tutorial video suggestion in his answer)

The rotating armature can be filled with ferrite or a material that is made from glue and iron powder - no need of complex pile of insulated foil shapes. Other possiblities: A bunch of painted iron nails or wires.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the positive and the negative terminal with one or more pieces of metal, you have the very definition of a short circuit.

Comment: if i don't stick the +ve and -ve ends of the wire on the metal shaft, but the wire is coiled on metal pieces locked on the shaft using nuts, will it short the circuit?

Comment: are the metal pieces were you stick the wires connected to the shaft, via metal?

Comment: yes, the shaft is a lead screw rod, go through 4 metal pieces with holes, lock them with metal nuts

Comment: It doesn't matter much if your metal is a screw, a bolt or a shaft, as long as it's all connected to each other, current will flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use laquer covered wire  (as you should) you can glue the wires to the shaft and remove the insulation on the outside  of the wire with sandpaper.

See this Spanish [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7C0WDsE9CLU), no sound needed.

Answer (score -1):

Needs pictures or diagrams!

Hard to visualise from such a description, but if "The brushes will lean on the metal shaft" without any insulator, then they will obviously short out. Do you have a normal commutator there?

The "thing wire coiled on" is called an *armature*, and is best made from a stack of soft iron plates.

Comment: i uploaded a diagram, i don't have a commutator there

Comment: @user10074 You have, however it is not normal.